# Ho do I specify how ActiveSupport::JSON.encode handles nested hash integer keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activesupport

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if I'm missing an option to specify how to handle integer keys of nested hashes when converting to JSON using rails `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode`. Example of the problem

```
$ rails console
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.22.1)

Frame number: 0/5
[1] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({outer: {1 => "a"}})
=> "{\"outer\":{\"1\":\"a\"}}"
```

As you can see, the inner hash key `1` has been converted to a string. I know there are various options to specify how to handle unknown classes/type and ActiveRecord specific things (like allowing joins with `:include`), but I would have thought that an integer as a 'native' type wouldn't require that sort of thing, and that nesting would be handled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In JSON, the “keys” must always be strings](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html).

```
=> a = { 1 => "1" }
#> {1=>"1"}
=> a.to_json
#> "{\"1\":\"1\"}"
=> JSON.parse(a.to_json)
#> {"1"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Okay, I did not know that. I would have thought that since integer keys are valid for  Objects in Javascript, they would be valid in JSON.